# How can I set the aspect ratio?

Tags: python, matplotlib, aspect-ratio

I'm trying to make a square plot (using imshow), i.e. aspect ratio of 1:1, but I can't. None of these work:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

ax = fig.add_subplot(111,aspect='equal')
ax = fig.add_subplot(111,aspect=1.0)
ax.set_aspect('equal')
plt.axes().set_aspect('equal')
```

It seems like the calls are just being ignored (a problem I often seem to have with matplotlib).

Comment: Did you try `ax.axis('equal')`, by chance?  As everyone's said, what you did should work, but `ax.axis` might be another route to try for a workaround.

Comment: http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/equal_aspect_ratio.html

Answer (score 112, accepted):

Third times the charm. My guess is that this is a bug and [Zhenya's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7965743/python-matplotlib-setting-aspect-ratio/7969475#7969475) suggests it's fixed in the latest version. I have version 0.99.1.1 and I've created the following solution:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

def forceAspect(ax,aspect=1):
    im = ax.get_images()
    extent =  im[0].get_extent()
    ax.set_aspect(abs((extent[1]-extent[0])/(extent[3]-extent[2]))/aspect)

data = np.random.rand(10,20)

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax.imshow(data)
ax.set_xlabel('xlabel')
ax.set_aspect(2)
fig.savefig('equal.png')
ax.set_aspect('auto')
fig.savefig('auto.png')
forceAspect(ax,aspect=1)
fig.savefig('force.png')
```

This is 'force.png':
[image]

Below are my unsuccessful, yet hopefully informative attempts.

***Second Answer:***

My 'original answer' below is overkill, as it does something similar to `axes.set_aspect()`. I think you want to use `axes.set_aspect('auto')`. I don't understand why this is the case, but it produces a square image plot for me, for example this script:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

data = np.random.rand(10,20)

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax.imshow(data)
ax.set_aspect('equal')
fig.savefig('equal.png')
ax.set_aspect('auto')
fig.savefig('auto.png')
```

Produces an image plot with 'equal' aspect ratio:
[image]
and one with 'auto' aspect ratio:
[image]

The code provided below in the 'original answer' provides a starting off point for an explicitly controlled aspect ratio, but it seems to be ignored once an imshow is called.

***Original Answer:***

Here's an example of a routine that will adjust the subplot parameters so that you get the desired aspect ratio:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def adjustFigAspect(fig,aspect=1):
    '''
    Adjust the subplot parameters so that the figure has the correct
    aspect ratio.
    '''
    xsize,ysize = fig.get_size_inches()
    minsize = min(xsize,ysize)
    xlim = .4*minsize/xsize
    ylim = .4*minsize/ysize
    if aspect < 1:
        xlim *= aspect
    else:
        ylim /= aspect
    fig.subplots_adjust(left=.5-xlim,
                        right=.5+xlim,
                        bottom=.5-ylim,
                        top=.5+ylim)

fig = plt.figure()
adjustFigAspect(fig,aspect=.5)
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax.plot(range(10),range(10))

fig.savefig('axAspect.png')
```

This produces a figure like so:
[image]

I can imagine if your having multiple subplots within the figure, you would want to include the number of y and x subplots as keyword parameters (defaulting to 1 each) to the routine provided. Then using those numbers and the `hspace` and `wspace` keywords, you can make all the subplots have the correct aspect ratio.

Comment: For cases where `get_images` is an empty list (as would happen with `ax.plot([0,1],[0,2])`, you can use `get_xlim` and `get_ylim`

Comment: It looks to me like this won't work if done with logscale.  I've added an answer which tests for that and handles it.  Feel free to incorporate that into your answer and then I'll remove mine.

Comment: The reason that the aspect looks unequal is because equal aspect means that visual distance in x will be the same as y. If the image is square, but the plot dx and dy are different, then that is not a 1:1 aspect ratio. The aspect ratio will be dy/dx in that case.

Answer (score 135):

A simple option using plt.gca() to get current axes and set aspect

```
plt.gca().set_aspect('equal')
```

in place of your last line

Comment: Best answer in my opinion. Simple and to the point

Comment: Definitely the best, I'd put 1.0 as the argument though, since the question is general.

Comment: This is the correct answer for 2D `plot`s.

Answer (score 25):

What is the `matplotlib` version you are running? I have recently had to upgrade to `1.1.0`, and with it, `add_subplot(111,aspect='equal')` works for me.

Comment: Works well for me in `matplotlib` version `2.0.2`. `jupyter notebook` version `5.0.0`. Thanks.

Answer (score 12):

After many years of success with the answers above, I have found this not to work again - but I did find a working solution for subplots at

https://jdhao.github.io/2017/06/03/change-aspect-ratio-in-mpl

With full credit of course to the author above (who can perhaps rather post here), the relevant lines are:

```
ratio = 1.0
xleft, xright = ax.get_xlim()
ybottom, ytop = ax.get_ylim()
ax.set_aspect(abs((xright-xleft)/(ybottom-ytop))*ratio)
```

The link also has a crystal clear explanation of the different coordinate systems used by matplotlib.

Thanks for all great answers received - especially @Yann's which will remain the winner.

Comment: The link to https://jdhao.github.io/2017/06/03/change-aspect-ratio-in-mpl is very valuable. This is an ever more complete exposition: https://matplotlib.org/tutorials/advanced/transforms_tutorial.html

Comment: This answer is great. Here is my implementation: `fig = plt.figure(); ax = fig.add_subplot(111); ax.set_aspect(x.size / y.size)`.

Comment: For some unknown reason, this works for me with ratio=0.5. Since this is purely from visual appearance, that might be approximate.

Answer (score 6):

In my case, the following setting works best:

```
plt.figure(figsize=(16,9))
```

where (16,9) is your plot aspect ratio.

Comment: A change from `fig = plt.figure()` to `fig = plt.figure(figsize=(16,9))` works perfectly, thank you!

Answer (score 3):

you should try with figaspect. It works for me. From the docs:

> Create a figure with specified aspect ratio.  If *arg* is a number, use that aspect ratio.  > If *arg* is an array, figaspect will
>   determine the width and height for a figure that would fit array
>   preserving aspect ratio.  The figure width, height in inches are
>   returned.  Be sure to create an axes with equal with and height, eg
>
> Example usage:

```
  # make a figure twice as tall as it is wide
  w, h = figaspect(2.)
  fig = Figure(figsize=(w,h))
  ax = fig.add_axes([0.1, 0.1, 0.8, 0.8])
  ax.imshow(A, **kwargs)

  # make a figure with the proper aspect for an array
  A = rand(5,3)
  w, h = figaspect(A)
  fig = Figure(figsize=(w,h))
  ax = fig.add_axes([0.1, 0.1, 0.8, 0.8])
  ax.imshow(A, **kwargs)
```

Edit: I am not sure of what you are looking for. The above code changes the canvas (the plot size). If you want to change the size of the matplotlib window, of the figure, then use:

```
In [68]: f = figure(figsize=(5,1))
```

this does produce a window of 5x1 (wxh).

Comment: Thanks for this - it does have some effect, in changing the aspect ratio of the canvas: To be more specific, I need to change the aspect ratio of the figure itself, which doing the following does not (apols formatting..): fig = plt.figure(figsize=(plt.figaspect(2.0)))

Answer (score 3):

This answer is based on  Yann's answer.  It will set the aspect ratio for linear or log-log plots.  I've used additional information from https://stackoverflow.com/a/16290035/2966723 to test if the axes are log-scale.

```
def forceAspect(ax,aspect=1):
    #aspect is width/height
    scale_str = ax.get_yaxis().get_scale()
    xmin,xmax = ax.get_xlim()
    ymin,ymax = ax.get_ylim()
    if scale_str=='linear':
        asp = abs((xmax-xmin)/(ymax-ymin))/aspect
    elif scale_str=='log':
        asp = abs((scipy.log(xmax)-scipy.log(xmin))/(scipy.log(ymax)-scipy.log(ymin)))/aspect
    ax.set_aspect(asp)
```

Obviously you can use any version of `log` you want, I've used `scipy`, but `numpy` or `math` should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `set_box_aspect(1)` on your axis object

[Example on the matplotlib docs](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/subplots_axes_and_figures/axes_box_aspect.html)