# project data defined on a sphere

Tags: matplotlib, plot, map-projections

I have some data defined on a sphere (a sphere not the earth): is it possible with Python 2.6 and matplotlib to draw them on map (of the type of Mercator map) "automatically" or do I have to project the data?

Edit: All of my data are lat-long.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It really depends on what you have and what you want: x-y and/or lat-lon? It looks like your question is similar to a problem I had and more-or-less answered:
[matplotlib and apect ratio of geographical-data plots](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18873623/matplotlib-and-apect-ratio-of-geographical-data-plots/18918410#18918410)

Comment: Then I think the same approach solves your problem. Just plot and see if it is correct.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using `set_aspect()`, using the reciprocal of the mean latitude of your data.

See [matplotlib and apect ratio of geographical-data plots](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18873623/matplotlib-and-apect-ratio-of-geographical-data-plots/18918410#34678673) for a working example.