# Imshow aspect doesn’t work well

Tags: python, matplotlib, aspect-ratio, imshow

I make numeric simulations and have problems with my plots... My simulation area is `6x35µm` with a resolution of `640x1024px`. 
When I want to plot my simulation data using `imshow`, and set the aspect ratio: `aspect=6/35`, then the height of the plot is correct but it is much to long? What am I doing wrong?

In the picture:

`top`: simulation mask, all plots should have the same aspect ratio.

`middle`: aspect is set to manually set to the aspect of the simulation mask (6/35)

`bottom`: aspect is set to 1

[image]

Here is my code

```
fig = pl.figure(num=None, figsize=(10, 10))
ax = fig.add_subplot(1,1,1)
img = ax.imshow(data, aspect=6./35)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You also need to account for the difference in resolution along both axis. For your y-axis you have 640 data points for 6 micrometers and for the x-axis 1024 data points for 35 micrometers. Matplotlib assumes both to be equal.

```
data = np.random.rand(640,1024)

fig, axs = plt.subplots(2,1, figsize=(10, 4))

aspect = 6 / 35

axs[0].set_title('aspect: %1.2f' % aspect)
axs[0].imshow(data, aspect=aspect, interpolation='none')

aspect = (6/35.) * (1024 / 640)

axs[1].set_title('aspect: %1.2f' % aspect)
axs[1].imshow(data, aspect=aspect, interpolation='none')
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is the following:

`img = ax.imshow(data, aspect = 6/35.)`

or in other words, make a float of the denominator. `6/35` is equal to zero. `6/35.` is not.

Hope that helps

Comment: Sorry, this istn't the problem... In my code should be the dot, thats correct. I edited it.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer somewhere elso in the forum...
[How can I set the aspect ratio in matplotlib?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7965743/python-matplotlib-setting-aspect-ratio)

```
def forceAspect(ax,aspect=1):
    im = ax.get_images()
    extent =  im[0].get_extent()
    ax.set_aspect(abs((extent[1]-extent[0])/(extent[3]-extent[2]))/aspect)
```