# matplotlib imshow display ratio fix to square

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have code that produces a plot based on the example below.  I would like to force the outputted plot to be a `128x128` square if possible instead of `64x128`.  The data I have is intended to be viewed as a square even though its matrix does not exhibit NxN properties.

Thank you.

```
import numpy as np
import pylab as pl

my_matrix = []
for x in range(128):
    row = []
    for value in range(64):
        row.append( float(value) / 63 )
    my_matrix.append(row)

array = np.matrix(my_matrix)
pl.axes()
pl.imshow(array, interpolation='none', cmap='jet', origin='lower')
pl.colorbar(shrink=0.95)
pl.xticks(())
pl.yticks(())
pl.show()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define the axes aspect ratio as follows:

```py
pl.axes().set_aspect(0.5)
```

The factor 0.5 compensates the aspect ration 128:64 = 2:1 of your data.

For further information you might look into [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7968690/3419103).

Comment: Do you also know how I can set my colorbar() ticks such that [-18, -14, -12, -10, -8, -6, -4, -2] where -18 is at the bottom and -2 is at the top.  Also -18 tick correlates to values closest to zero and -2 tick correlates to values closest to 1.

Comment: @Matt: Have a look into the [```clim``` argument](http://matplotlib.org/api/cm_api.html#matplotlib.cm.ScalarMappable.set_clim), e.g. ```pl.imshow(..., clim=[-18,-2])```. This way you can limit the color range. But it should correspond to the data, so you might scale them accordingly: ```pl.imshow(array * (-18), ..., clim=[-18,-2])```.

Comment: Ok Thanks.  I essentially have a dataset which represents different orders of magnitude.  from `10E-18` to `zero` in increments of `10E-2`.  I'm a total noob to `matplotlib` so I appreciate it!