# Matplotlib imshow() grid uneven when grid size is large

Tags: python, matplotlib, imshow

I am trying to use the imshow() function in matplotlib to plot color values in a 177 X 177 grid. When I run the following code on a small (30X30) grid (i.e. I set `width = 30`), the image that it produces has nice, evenly sized squares. When I run it on a larger grid (150X150), the squares are not evenly proportioned. Some are stretched in one or both dimensions. Here's a simplified version of the code I'm using:

```
grid = [[]]*width
for i in range(width):
    grid[i] = [[]]*width
    for j in range(width):
        grid[i][j] = (random(), random(), random())

plt.imshow(grid, interpolation="none", aspect=1)
plt.savefig("test.png")
```

Any idea how to make the grid even? I've tried all of the aspect ratio stuff discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7965743/how-can-i-set-the-aspect-ratio-in-matplotlib?lq=1), but it didn't seem to solve the problem. I'm using Python 2.7.6 and matplotlib version 1.3.1.

Edit:
Here is a picture  showing what the cells from the large gird look like if I zoom all the way in. This was obtained using a slightly different coloring function, in which clusters of 9 cells are colored by increasing hue. This more clearly shows the uneven shapes. I can include the code if you want, but I get the same behavior with the (much less complicated) random code.
 [image]

And here's what it looks (again, zoomed in) like when I use a small grid:

[image]

Comment: I can not reproduce your problem, please post images.  Also, `grid = np.random.rand((width, width, 3))` will replace your nested loops.

Comment: Image posted. And good catch on the code! I wrote this code quickly so as to provide a simpler example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, I figured it out. The problem was that I wasn't using a high enough dpi when I saved the image. `plt.savefig("test.png", dpi=1000)`yields an image in which even a large grid is depicted with evenly-sized squares.

By not increasing the dpi for the larger grid, I was effectively trying to plot more information in the same amount of pixels, so the resolution was decreasing to the point where the cells were becoming miss-shapen.