# How to obtain a fixed height in pixels, fixed data x/y aspect ratio and automatically remove remove horizontal whitespace margin in Matplotlib?

Tags: matplotlib

Let's take this as a starting point based on: [Specifying and saving a figure with exact size in pixels](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13714454/specifying-and-saving-a-figure-with-exact-size-in-pixels/64632093#64632093)

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import sys

import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib as mpl

h = int(sys.argv[1])
fig, ax = plt.subplots(nrows=2, ncols=1)
t = np.arange(-10., 10., 1.)
a = ax[0]
a.set_aspect(1)
a.plot(t, t, '.')
a = ax[1]
a.plot(t, -t, '.')
a.set_aspect(1)
plt.savefig(
    'main.png',
    format='png',
    dpi=h/fig.get_size_inches()[1],
    facecolor='y',
)
```

which allows me to do:

```
./main.py 400 && identify main.png
```

to generate an image with the correct desired height of 400 pixels:

```
main.png PNG 533x400 533x400+0+0 8-bit sRGB 6058B 0.000u 0:00.000
```

[image]

However, there's a lot of empty space to the left and right of the plots. This space is due to the fixed aspect ratio of `1` that I also want (x and y data have the same sizes). We can confirm that by removing the `set_aspect` calls, which gives a figure with reasonably sized margins:

[image]

but I want the 1/1 aspect ratio as well.

I've tried to remove this space with several methods from: [Removing white space around a saved image in matplotlib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11837979/removing-white-space-around-a-saved-image-in-matplotlib) but none gave what I wanted.

For example, if I add:

```
plt.savefig(bbox_inches='tight',
```

I get the desired image:

[image]

but the height is not 400 anymore as I want it to be:

```
main.png PNG 189x345 189x345+0+0 8-bit sRGB 4792B 0.000u 0:00.000
```

Or if I try instead to add:

```
plt.tight_layout(pad=0)
```

the height is correct, but it didn't remove the horizontal space:

[image]

One thing I could do is to explicitly set the width as in:

```
import sys

import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib as mpl

h = int(sys.argv[1])
w = int(sys.argv[2])
fig, ax = plt.subplots(nrows=2, ncols=1)
wi, hi = fig.get_size_inches()
fig.set_size_inches(hi*(w/h), hi)
t = np.arange(-10., 10., 1.)
a = ax[0]
a.set_aspect(1)
a.plot(t, t, '.')
a = ax[1]
a.plot(t, -t, '.')
a.set_aspect(1)
plt.tight_layout(pad=1)
plt.savefig(
    'main.png',
    format='png',
    dpi=h/hi,
    facecolor='y',
)
```

and run that with:

```
./main.py 400 250 && identify main.png
```

where 250 is selected by trial and error, and that does give the exact pixel dimensions and good looking output:

[image]

but I'd rather not have to do the trial and error to find the value 250, I want that to be determined automatically by matplotlib.

This might be what [matplotlib: Set width or height of figure without changing aspect ratio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28617263/matplotlib-set-width-or-height-of-figure-without-changing-aspect-ratio) is asking, but it is hard to be sure without concrete examples.

Tested on matplotlib==3.2.2.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I understood your question, but if you want to limit the whitespace in a figure with a 1x2 subplot layout, you simply have to create a figure with a width that's half the height:

```
h = 400
nrows = 2
w = h/nrows
dpi = 100

fig, ax = plt.subplots(nrows=nrows, ncols=1, figsize=(w/dpi, h/dpi), dpi=dpi)

t = np.arange(-10., 10., 1.)
a = ax[0]
a.set_aspect(1)
a.plot(t, t, '.')
a = ax[1]
a.plot(t, -t, '.')
a.set_aspect(1)
plt.tight_layout(pad=1)
plt.savefig(
    'main.png',
    format='png',
    dpi=dpi,
    facecolor='y',
)
```

`>> identify main.png`

> `main.png PNG 200x400 200x400+0+0 8-bit sRGB 6048B 0.000u 0:00.000`

[image]

Comment: OK, I should have tested more with that. That solution is reasonable. But it is a bit annoying to have to do nrow/ncol manipulations myself. And the space would also return in case other vertical non-plot-area elements were added,e.g. `a.set_title('A', fontdict=dict(fontsize='75'))`. Although maybe in practice that won't be common (that font size is exaggeratedly large).

Comment: I also noticed now that the aspect ratio would also need to be taken into account in the more general case (this answer works for the specific case of `a.set_aspect(1)`).

Answer (score 0):

**SVG output + `plt.savefig(bbox_inches='tight'` + Inkscape convert**

This is terrible, but it does what I want without a lot of extra boilerplate, so here we go:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import sys

import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib as mpl

h = int(sys.argv[1])
fig, ax = plt.subplots(nrows=2, ncols=1)
t = np.arange(-10., 10., 1.)
a = ax[0]
a.set_aspect(1)
a.plot(t, t, '.')
a = ax[1]
a.plot(t, -t, '.')
a.set_aspect(1)
plt.savefig(
    'main.svg',
    format='svg',
    dpi=h/fig.get_size_inches()[1],
    facecolor='y',
    bbox_inches='tight',
)
```

and then:

```
inkscape -b FFF -e main.png -h 400 main.svg
```

output:

[image]

`bbox_inches='tight'` gives a decent looking image without too much borders, but makes me lose the exact size, so we use the SVG output as a way to work around that.

This should work well since SVG is a vector format, and therefore should scale to any size seamlessly.

I use Inkscape for the conversion because Imagemagick requires you to manually calculate the resolution:

- https://superuser.com/questions/598849/imagemagick-convert-how-to-produce-sharp-resized-png-files-from-svg-files/1602059#1602059
- [How to convert a SVG to a PNG with ImageMagick?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9853325/how-to-convert-a-svg-to-a-png-with-imagemagick)

Tested on Inkscape 0.92.5.