# Forcing a colormap to be square

Tags: python, matplotlib, colormap

I am working on Python with the `matplotlib` library and I have a problem with color maps dimension.

I have some target variable `target` that depends on two variables `x` and `y` - i.e. my data `target` is a matrix with the variable `x` being rows and `y` columns. I want to represent `target` in a color map with respect to `x` and `y`. The problem is that I have more values for `x` than for `y`, hence if I plot a color map I get a rectangle - a rather ugly one because I have many more values for `x` than for `y`.

I would rather have rectangular "pixels" in the color map and a square map, rather than square "pixels" but a rectangular color map - or at least I would like to compare the two visualizations.

My question is: how can I force the color map to be square?

This is my current code - the `cmap` variable simply allows me to define my custom color scale:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.pyplot as clr

target = ...

cmap = clr.LinearSegmentedColormap.from_list('custom blue', 
                                             ['#DCE6F1','#244162'],
                                             N=128)
plt.matshow(target, cmap=cmap)
plt.colorbar(cmap='custom blue')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Andreas's answer works on my computer. You might see a slightly different result that with your code because imshow() will by default interpolate the image, therefore the picture will be different compared to matshow(). But the `aspect` parameter works on both. So either feed it to matshow(), or disable the interpolation in imshow():

```
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax.matshow(np.random.rand(32, 64), cmap='rainbow', aspect=2)
plt.show()

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax.imshow(np.random.rand(32, 64), cmap='rainbow', aspect=2, interpolation="None")
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 2):

What's your `matplotlib` version?
If it's newer than `1.1.0` then you can try this:

```
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax.imshow(np.random.rand(32, 64), cmap='rainbow', aspect=2)
plt.show()
```

[image]

This gives you rectangular pixels with square figure shape.
You should replace `np.random.rand(32, 64)` by your data, and define the aspect ratio you like. Also, please refer to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7965743/how-can-i-set-the-aspect-ratio-in-matplotlib/7969475#7969475). There are other solutions you might be interested in.