# How to do a matshow or imshow, but display the axis values as bin boundaries (i.e as you would on a 2d frequency/density plot)

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, histogram2d

I need to do a 2d density-like plot. However I calculate the "densities" myself. So essentially I have an `NxM` array of values that I can only plot with `plt.matshow` (or imshow).

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
im = ax.matshow(value_array)
ax.set_xticklabels(x_edges - 2.5)
ax.set_yticklabels(y_edges - 0.25)
```

However, in this case, the axis values are the pixels in the plot, whereas I really want it to show some user-defined values. So I manually change the tick labels as above.

This still leaves a problem. `matshow` still thinks the tick labels are labelling the "pixels" in the image, so the tick labels are printed in the "middle" of each pixel square. However, like I said, what I'm really trying to plot is more like a density plot, so each "pixel square" represents a bin in x,y space. It would make a lot more sense to have the tick labels printed *on* the square edges, like the way it's done for histogram plots and frequency plots in general.

Should I keep using matshow for this or is there another function that does this? For example, can I use the `plt.hist2d` but manually set the "heights" without entering data as a bunch of samples? Otherwise, how do I make `plt.matshow` put the tick labels in the way I want them?

Comment: Is the `extent` option of `imshow` what you are looking for?

Comment: @TomdeGeus I don't think so. As far as I can understand, extent would only affect the range of the image (like xlim or ylim), though I may have misunderstood how it works. Basically in the documenation on extent, https://matplotlib.org/tutorials/intermediate/imshow_extent.html, you see in the plots that the axis actually starts at -0.5, and goes to like 6.5, while the tick labels are in the centres of the pixels, at 0.0, 1.0, etc... So if I could offset the tick locations by 0.5, it would do what I want (or better shift the whole image by -0.5 pixels).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure that I understand you correctly. What I understand is that you want to take a 2-d histogram of your data, and want to show the count/density of each bin using a color, while retaining the real coordinates of the bin-edges.

Indeed you can use a combination of `numpy.histogram2d` and `matplotlib.pyplot.imshow`.

> Let me start by a warning. With`imshow` you display pixels. Implicitly you therefore assume that bins are uniformly sized along each axis. They may have a different width and height, but the width/height of each bin has be equal for the representation to be fair.

To achieve what I think you want you'll have to use something like this:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

N = 100000
x = np.random.randn(N)
y = np.random.weibull(2.,N)

P, xedges, yedges = np.histogram2d(x, y, bins=(np.linspace(-4,+5,10), np.linspace(0,4,21)), density=True)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

cax = ax.imshow(P.T, extent=(xedges[0], xedges[-1], yedges[0], yedges[-1]),
  origin='lower', interpolation='nearest', clim=(0,.4), cmap='afmhot_r')

cbar = fig.colorbar(cax,aspect=10)

ax.set_aspect('auto')

ax.set_xlabel('x')
ax.set_ylabel('y')

plt.savefig('test.png')
plt.show()
```

Which plots

[image]

The tricky part is that to get a natural output:

- You have to overwrite `imshow`'s default of putting the origin of the top of the image. As indicated, this you do with the `origin='lower'` option.
- You have to plot the transposed output of `numpy.histogram`, because `imshow` shows the matrix as-is, while the output of `numpy.histogram` show has shape `(nx, ny)`: the values along the x-axis correspond to rows.
- You might have to change the aspect ratio, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7968690/2646505).

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I think it's working, but I've still got a few issues (also I'm using matshow in case it's different). First of all, my x axis ranges from 0 to 40, my y axis from 0.5 to 3.5, so just like your picture, the plot is very compressed vertically. Is this expected, and should I just try to stretch out using some figure params then? Secondly: I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong, but it's not putting the full range of values on the y axis (i.e I manually set the tick labels, but it puts one on every second tick, and overall it's got half the range I'd expect).

Comment: @LimokPalantaemon With respect to the aspect ratio: I have updated my answer, including `set_aspect`. With respect to the ticks, it's difficult to say without seeing the actual code and the problem. You could consider opening a new question?

Comment: hey, I've been looking into setting the aspect, but it doesn't work with a simple `set_aspect('equal').` Moreover, I'm starting to be convinced that this was a bit more complicated a question than I first thought. Setting the extent, and your answer, helped, but I think there is another step to make after this. I'm thinking of keeping the idea of 'pixels' in the extent and not stretching the figure; instead I will try to relabel the ticks directly by position. I will post an answer below (will still keep yours as the answer). A combination of both might help others.

Comment: @LimokPalantaemon You should set it to **auto** not equal. Or you should manually specify the aspect ratio.

Comment: Ah I see, yes it works with `auto`. Sorry my bad. This is definitely the better way to do it. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

As an addition to @TomdeGeus answer, here is something that could help. Since I needed to plot a figure where the y-axis stretches from 0.5 to 3.5 while the x-axis stretches from 0 to 40, it was very compressed in the image, and I may have had to force the aspect ratio, which wasn't working. There was also something wrong with the ticks it displaying.

**However after fixing the aspect ratio, I would definitely recommend you follow Tom de Geus's answer, it's the correct way to do this.**

So I still plot the image on "pixel" coordinates, i.e choose the extent so that the x- and y-axes count the pixels, but starting at 0, rather than -0.5 like the default behaviour of `plt.imshow()`

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()

im = ax.matshow(value_grid, origin='lower', extent=(0, len(x_edges)-1, 0, len(y_edges)-1)
```

Where `len(y_edges) - 1` counts the number of pixels I want in the y-axis (and `y_edges` is a list containing the values of the bin boundaries I want to display on the y-axis as before.

Then I manually replace the tick labels, but I also need to correctly map them to the right ticks.

```
ax.set_xticks(list(range(len(x_edges))))
ax.set_xticklabels(x_edges)
ax.set_yticks(list(range(len(y_edges))))
ax.set_yticklabels(y_edges)
```

This preserves the square nature of the pixels produced by `imshow`, however you have to keep in mind that the underlying axis is still defined in terms of pixels (i.e if I want to place a point on the coordinate (25.0, 2.0), it wouldn't actually look like it ended up at that location below.

[image]

Comment: I don't think this is correct in general: you make strong assumptions on your `x_edges` and `y_edges` (or in fact you are plotting the index, not their coordinate as you indicated you wanted).

Comment: Sorry, not sure what you mean. I do concede this is definitely a weaker way, and it only gets done the specific thing I wanted. As you say, I'm plotting by index but then I'm just relabeling the tick-labels to display what I intended. That's why I'm leaving your answer as the successful one.

Comment: Now I see. What in my solution was still not working for you?\

Comment: Now that the aspect ratio is fixed it's fine. Another thing was that I didn't notice that I was still relabelling my tick labels like I do in the question, so that's also why the tick labels seemed wrong. I would say now it's fine.