# Python: set aspect ratio of figure to 1

Tags: python, matplotlib, aspect-ratio

How do I get a figure to have a 1:1 aspect ratio? I currently have the following figure

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

circle1 = plt.Circle((0.5, 0.5), 0.2, color='r')
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.add_artist(circle1)
```

But the x-axis is bigger than the y-axis. I tried using the command I found [here](https://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/equal_aspect_ratio.html) :

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

circle1 = plt.Circle((0.5, 0.5), 0.2, color='r')
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.add_artist(circle1)

plt.axes().set_aspect('equal', 'datalim')
```

but then the circle I drew disappears.

How can I set an equal aspect ratio?

Comment: It would be `ax.set_aspect('equal', 'datalim')` instead.

Comment: import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

circle1 = plt.Circle((0.5, 0.5), 0.2, color='r')
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.add_artist(circle1)
ax.set_aspect('equal')

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I set the aspect ratio in matplotlib?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7965743/how-can-i-set-the-aspect-ratio-in-matplotlib)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the aspect kw to your fig, ax statement:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(subplot_kw={'aspect': 1})
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to change the aspect ratio of your `ax` at any time rather than when it's created, you can call:

```
ax.set_aspect("equal")
```

as documented [here](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.set_aspect.html).