# Matplotlib image does not scale to full size of window

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to plot a figure that sizes to the screen aspect ratio. Below is my code:

```
dataset = np.random.rand(24,365)
plt.figure(0)
xgrid = np.arange(1,366)
ygrid = np.arange(24)
data_map = plt.pcolormesh(xgrid, ygrid, dataset)
cbar = plt.colorbar(data_map)
plt.tight_layout()
plt.savefig('name',dpi=600)
```

This is the resulting image:

[image: Output image with black space on the side.]

As you can see, there is a black empty space on either side of the image. I am trying to find a way to make the image fill the entire screen, so that the x-axis utilizes all the horizontal space and the data doesn't look so clustered. How would I do this?

I tried to use `plt.figure(0,figsize=(16,9))` since my monitor has an aspect ratio of 16:9, but it still does not entirely fill the screen (as well as creating a lot of empty space to the right of the colorbar). Regardless, I was hoping to find a solution that is independent of aspect ratio.

Comment: Does this help you? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7965743/how-can-i-set-the-aspect-ratio

Comment: Yes I looked at that thread, and I tried a few of those but to no avail. I tried `plt.figure(figsize=(16,9))` as I originally mentioned. I also tried `ax.set_aspect('auto')` and this didn't work either - although I wasn't quite sure if I implemented it correctly since I don't have a subplot in mine. The code I tried looks like this:

`plt.figure(0)`
...
`cbar = plt.colorbar(data_map)`
`ax = plt.gca()`
`ax.set_aspect('auto')`
`plt.tight_layout()`
`plt.savefig('name',dpi=600)`

Comment: This is a non-issue question. The figure is the plot with the white border. You are looking at the image in an image viewer, and the image does not take up the full screen. In fact, the image size is only 55% so the image is viewable within the window.

Comment: Yes my question is how do I save the image such that the image is at the same aspect ratio as my monitor so that it fills up the entire screen. Right now, it is not utilizing the entire screen space.

Answer (score 0):

You can maybe try "plt.get_current_fig_manager()". For Windows user, you can add:

```
mng = plt.get_current_fig_manager()
mng.window.state('zoomed')
```

For Mac user, you can add "full_screen_toggle()":

```
mng = plt.get_current_fig_manager()
mng.full_screen_toggle()
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. When I add those lines in (for Windows), I get the following error `'FigureManagerBase' object has no attribute 'window'`. How can I fix this?

Comment: Did you use 'TKAgg' as the backend? You can maybe check this post as well. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12439588/how-to-maximize-a-plt-show-window